# External play button for YouTube embed video player

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

```
<div id=player></div>
<div id=playvideo style= "width:40px; height:80px; background-color:#2b2b2b;" >
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '448',
          width: '763',
          playerVars: {
              'showinfo': 0,
              'controls': 0,
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLD7SqVUGDdDBw_xmMKTDF5MlBwys_KlUk'
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // event.target.playVideo();
      }

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          player.stopVideo();
        }
      }
    </script>
```

I have an embed code like that, and I want the div named "playvideo" acts like YouTube's play button, I think it's an easy one but I'm new on JavaScript, can anybody have an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you can use YouTube's Player API function:
**player.playVideo()**

So ... HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="play_this_video()">Play my video</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
function play_this_video(){
 player.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: This sometimes doesn't work for me. When it fails, I get this in console and get "TypeError: player.playVideo is not a function".